# Postgres: Count all INSERT queries executed in the past 1 minute

Tags: postgresql

I can do currently active count of all INSERT queries executed on the PostgreSQL server like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity where query like 'INSERT%'
```

But is there a way to count all INSERT queries executed on the server in a given period of time? E.g. in the past minute?

I have a bunch of tables into which I send a lot of inserts and I would like to somehow aggregate how many rows I am inserting per minute. I could code a solution for this, but it'd be so much easier if this was possible to somehow extract directly from the server.

Any type of stats like this, in a certain period of time, would be very helpful, an average time it takes for the query to process, or knowing the bandwidth that goes through per minute, etc.

Note: I am using PostgreSQL 12

Comment: Are you using automatically generated primary keys backed by a sequence? Then you could check the current sequence value, if an approximation is good enough.

Comment: how would I go about it?

Comment: Use the `currval` function.

Answer (score 1):

If not already done, install pg_stat_statements extension and take some snapshots of the view pg_stat_statements: the diff will give the number of queries executed between 2 snapshots.

Note: It doesn’t save each individual query, rather it parameterizes them and then saves the aggregated result.

See https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2019/02/08/the-most-useful-postgres-extension-pg-stat-statements/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can use the [audit trigger](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger).

This audit will create a table that register `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and  `DELETE` actions. So you can adapt. So every time that your database runs one of those commands, the audit table register the action, the table and the time of the action. So, it will be easy to do a `COUNT()` on desired table with a `WHERE` from a minute ago.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't come across anything solid, so I have created a table where I log a number of insert transactions using a script that runs as a cron job. It was simple enough to implement and I do not get estimations, but the real values instead. I actually count all new rows inserted to tables in a given interval.